# Gradle project for unit and functional tests

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have first created a functional test for my application and it was working fine.
Then I added unit tests (using Robolectric + Roboguice + Mockito) and they are also working fine. However, now my functional test cannot even start, throwing exception like `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bla.bla.MainActivity`

It took me a few hours (and the luck to read a hint somewhere in SO, but I lost it and I cannot link to it) that I need to check the logcat output for real information. This pointed out that there are a lot of issues, because the code is compiled with shadow classes from Robolectric... 
Therefore to fix this, I think I need to create two separate tasks (or at least one new) that will handle separately the compilation of unit tests and the compilation of functional test.

My unit tests are in:
`\src\androidTest\java\com\bla\bla\tests`
and my functional test (hopefully it will be **tests** soon) is in:
`\src\androidTest\java\com\bla\bla\tests\functional`

So what are the steps needed to fulfill this?
I guess I need to create new sourceSet, but how to tell which files should be there and do I need only test files (only those in \src\androidTest\java\com\bla\bla\tests\functional) or I need also the application source files.
I've been looking for something like quickstart examples, something documented so that I can easily digest it (because I already lost a day for this issue), but without success. Maybe I am not looking for the correct keywords, so if you know of something like this, a link will be very helpful too.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
        applicationId "com.bla.bla"
        testApplicationId "com.bla.bla.tests"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {

    androidTestCompile files('libs/robolectric-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/robotium-solo-5.2.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    androidTestCompile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/roboguice-2.0.jar')


    compile files('libs/weberknecht.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar')
    compile files('libs/roboguice-2.0.jar')
}
```

I am using:

- Android Studio 0.8.10
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2 (I guess this is the android gradle plugin)
- gradle 1.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a project in GitHub (mainly for personal use, but feel free to copy it). https://github.com/tas-morf/AndroidUnitTestTemplate
It has both unit tests (with Robolectric and Mockito) and instrumentation tests (with Espresso). As a bonus it also has integration with volley. I just use this because it helps me start most of my projects, but the build script and folder structure there should answer your questions. I've also included all the links to the other projects that helped achieve this. Keep in mind that this is a work in progress.

Comment: How do you compile and assemble test apk? With **assembleDebugTest** task?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot the most important part, which is how you use it! Indeed, assembeDebugTest will compile the test apk, but you probably need the following tasks: 'gradlew test' to run only unit tests and 'gradlew connectedAndroidTest' to run the instrumentation tests. In theory 'gradlew check' should run all of them, but I think a task dependency is not set yet. I'll add it at some point later.

Comment: Actually sorry, 'gradlew check' is not supposed to run the instrumentation tests, only unit and lint checks. So it's fine as it is.

Comment: I have some issues with the compilation. The external dependencies are not found somehow... But I have not made all the changes. I still have my instrumentation(functional) tests in a subpackage of unit tests, and I think there is a change needed there that will be essential. I will continue maybe tomorrow with it. Thanks, this was helpful so far.

Comment: I placed my instrumentation tests in `\src\androidTest\java\com\bla\bla\tests\functional` and set `testApplicationId "com.bla.bla.tests.functional"`. Then I placed my unit tests into `\src\test\java\com\bla\bla\` and finally everything works.